# How to solve this error ( duplicate entry: com/google/gson/annotations/Expose.class? )

Tags: java, android, gradle, gson

each time I try to build an APK, this error keep showing !? I've tried almost all the soultoins mention on the site, but no luck!

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>
> > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: 
> >         java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/gson/annotations/Expose.class

**My gradle file:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.1'


    lintOptions {
        quiet true
        abortOnError false
        ignoreWarnings true
    }
    configurations {
        all*.exclude group: 'commons-io'

    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'BinaryEncoder.java'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxxx.xxxxx"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.2"
        multiDexEnabled true
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "mips"
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java {
                exclude 'com.twilio:client-android:1.2.18.org.apache.http.lejacy.jar.org.apache.BinaryEncoder.java'
                exclude 'org.apache.commons.codec.BinaryEncoder.java'
            }
        }
        androidTest {
            java {
                exclude 'commons-codec-1.10/**'
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
     compile('com.twilio:client-android:1.2.18') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.commons', module: 'commons-io'
    }
    compile project(':example')
    compile project(':zoomcommonlib')
    compile project(':zoommobilertc')

    compile("com.github.hotchemi:permissionsdispatcher:2.4.0") {
         exclude module: "support-v13"
    }

    compile('com.stripe:stripe-android:4.1.5') {
        transitive = true;
        exclude  group: 'com.google.code.gson', module: 'gson'
    }
    compile('com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0') {
        transitive = true;
        exclude  group: 'com.google.code.gson', module: 'gson'
    }

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.2.0'
     compile 'lib.kingja.switchbutton:switchbutton:1.1.3'
    compile 'com.orhanobut:hawk:2.0.1'
     compile 'com.afollestad:material-camera:0.4.4'
    compile 'com.werb.pickphotoview:pickphotoview:0.3.0'
     compile 'com.github.Kennyc1012:BottomSheet:2.3.4'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:11.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:11.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
     compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.14.4'
    compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.1.8'
    compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.6.0'
    compile 'com.amitshekhar.android:android-networking:1.0.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.hotchemi:permissionsdispatcher-processor:2.4.0'
 }
```

---

Here's some solutions that I've tried and did **not** work:

1. I've added those `transitive = true; exclude  group: 'com.google.code.gson', module: 'gson' for`retrofit`and`stripe` dependencies
2. I deleted the gson dependency
3. I wanted to delete the jar file for `gson` library but I couldn't find it inside `libs` folder !?
4. `multiDexEnabled true` was already added and did no effect
5. I've deleted `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])`

I think it has something to do with the **`Zoom`** module or with **`Stripe`** any help.. !?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, first.. thanks guys for ur help anyhow..! but I'm making this as the accepted answer since it's the one that worked out for me!

---

**Step 1**
I searched for the duplicated class in the whole project using (Double Shift)
and it showed me which library is also using the same class..! in my case it was `zoommobilertc`

**Step 2**

I tried excluding the gson module of that library like this:

```
compile project(':zoommobilertc'){
   exclude  group: 'com.google.code.gson', module: 'gson'
}
```

..but it didn't work, and it give me error that I think it has something to do with `exclude` . I tried a few solution but no luck!

**So.. I did this instead ..**

- Open Project View
- Open External Libraries
- Find the library which's `zoommobilertc` and unfold its folder
- Delete `Gson` jar file that shows.!

**Step 3**

After that, I synced the project and tried to build an apk, bu this error showed:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'. > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing java process with main class com.android.dx.command.Main with arguments {--dex --num-threads=4 --multi-dex --main-dex-list E:\*****\*****\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\debug\maindexlist.txt --output E:\*****\*****\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dex\debug\folders\1000\1f\main E:\*****\*****\app\build\intermediates\transforms\jarMerging\debug\jars\1\1f\combined.jar}
```

Then after searching I found a fix:

I added this inside *build.gradle* file within android section:

```
android{
//..
 dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
//..
}
```

..and this line inside *local.properties* file

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-XX\:MaxHeapSize\=512m -Xmx512m
```

---

**Done**

Answer (score 4):

You could try to get the dependency tree and figure out which package it is.

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: Try gradle dependencies or gradlew if you're using the wrapper. There's ./gradlew app:dependencies for Android. But not sure if it is still the same command.

Comment: still couldn't find the package..!

Comment: How does your dependency tree looks like?

Comment: I tried printing it from terminal, this error shows: `E:\****\*****>gradlew app:dependencies
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'E:\*****\****\app\build.gradle' line: 130

* What went wrong:
Could not compile build file 'E:\*****\******\app\build.gradle'.
> startup failed:
  build file 'E:\*******\******\app\build.gradle': 130: unexpected char: 0xFFFF @ line 130, column 2.
     }
      ^

  1 error`

Comment: That's not the same. I would like to know, which libs includes the same packages. Or is there a lib using the same packages name which shouldn't. Is there a library using an old version to exclude.

I cannot see this with this screenshots.

Comment: I've already posted the solution, the screenshot is missing the last three  libs sorry, but its the last libs that has the a duplicated Gson jar file, I delete it mainly since using exude didn't work and it worked.. see the accepted answer to gain more info, thanks anyway man for ur help.!

Answer (score 2):

Find out the dependency that causes above Error and exclude `gson`
as follows from your dependency,

```
compile ('your_dependency'){
    exclude group : 'com.google.code.gson'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In android studio terminal execute

```
./gradlew clean
```

and perform the following and rebuild

Try adding this to your dependencies

```
compile'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

and in manifest add this

```
android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
```

in the application tag

Comment: what is in your lib folder. does it contain the gson.jar file or any related jar file ? try removing that and rebuild.

Comment: Try adding this to your dependencies `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'` and in manifest  add this `android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"` in the application tag

Comment: let me know if that helps :)

Comment: it didn't work too, here's what my libs folder contains https://image.ibb.co/k1UFBv/aaaaaaaaa.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I had my gson.jar in my libs folder.
I fixed my duplicate entries by retaining the line below:
`implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])`

And deleting this entry here:
`implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.7'`

Answer (score 0):

add below code

```
configurations {
    implementation.exclude module: 'gson' //Remove duplicate dependencies： gson
    implementation.exclude module: 'okhttp' //Remove duplicate dependencies： okhttp
}
```